# AWS Glue: --extra-files parameter is not recognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am specifying `--extra-files` as job parameter on Glue, yet front end is not happy with it as this picture shows:

[image: --extra-files not recognizied by front end]

I am anyway able to save my job and run it succesfully:

```
def read_yaml(config_file_name: str) -> dict:

    with open(config_file_name, 'r') as stream:
        try:
            return yaml.safe_load(stream)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            logger.info(exc)

config = read_yaml(config_file_name=CONFIG_FILE_NAME)
logger.info(config)
```

What is then very weird is that that if I check job parameters again, then `-extra-files` is disappeared, and if I run the job again it still reads my config file stored in S3.

Anyone has an explanation for: (1) why `--extra-files` generates a front end error, and (2) why the job runs smoothly although `--extra-files` is not set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just one of the quirks of AWS Glue.
'--extra-files' is equivalent of 'Referenced Files Path' on the UI console.

Typically, when creating a new Glue job using CLI or CloudFormation, we use '--extra-files' to set this value. However, on the console, this parameter can be set up in the section 'Security Configuration, script libraries, and job parameters' ---> 'Referenced Files Path'

Once successfully set up, you will no longer see it as a separate key in the 'Job Parameters' section. Rather, it will shown in the job details tab with *(believe it or not)* a totally new name - 'Other lib path'

Comment: I want to use this option and what you described happens correctly, however i get the error 'Considering file without prefix as a python extra file' and the file is not downloaded in the job current directory

Comment: @Simon30 is it a Python Shell job or PySpark one?